# Getting SmackException NoResponseException while creating a new group using Smack 4.1

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack

I am using the below code to create Multi user group but getting Timeout error, even if my timeout error is 10sec.

```
public void createGroup() {

    String roomId = "Group_test003" + "@icoveri.com";
    String nick = "Grouptest";

    try {

        MultiUserChatManager manager = multiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

        MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(roomId);

        muc.create(nick);

        Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();

        Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();

        List<FormField> fields = form.getFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
            FormField field = (FormField) fields.get(i);
            if (!FormField.Type.hidden.equals(field.getType()) && field.getVariable() != null) {

                submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
            }
        }

        List owners = new ArrayList();
        owners.add(user1234 + "@icoveri.com");
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", owners);

        muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);

    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The error which I am getting is

> org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response
>   received within reply timeout. Timeout was 10000ms (~10s). Used
>   filter: AndFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (full):
>   Group_test003@iscoveri.com/Grouptest, StanzaTypeFilter:
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence).
>
> at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:229)
>   at
>   org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.enter(MultiUserChat.java:311)
>   at
>   org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.createOrJoin(MultiUserChat.java:400)
>   at
>   org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.createOrJoin(MultiUserChat.java:376)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution. The problem was in my service i.e. iscoveri.com. I had to use different service name to create the group.

Answer (score 0):

I also have spent a couple hours trying to correct the same error; in my case, the problem happened when I used `XMPPBOSHConnection`, but not when using `XMPPTCPConnection`.